# how to cache jquery ajax load requests

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a simple question here, I have a [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) with 2 radio buttons, every time I click a radio button, a [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) Ajax request is made and the content below my radio buttons is replaced by my Ajax response. The content does not change, it is always the same, how do I cache the content so that it gets displayed faster on subsequent clicks of my radio buttons?

I tried using [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and set the `cache` option to `true`, but for some reason that did not work (everytime I click my radio buttons, the Ajax calls still occur). Any idea how I can do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the cache option to true

Comment: Is the server side application writing the cache header properly?